# Reduce callback modying wrong array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm trying to create a copy of my state dataMonth every time it changes, that copy is dataYear. I used the spread operator to create a brand new object with only the content copied.

I have to declare dataYear outside the useEffect since I want to use it later on in the global scope.

```
const [dataMonth, setDataMonth] = useState(null);
var dataYear = {};
```

I used reduce on my property 'data' to sum up the 12 months worth of value.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (dataMonth !== null) {
        dataYear = { ...dataMonth };
        dataYear.labels = ["Année " + year];
        dataYear.datasets.forEach((value) => {
            value.data.reduce((prev, val) => {
                return value.data = prev + val;
            });
            value.data = [value.data];
        });
    }
}, [dataMonth]);
```

The 'labels' property is changed only in the dataYear object as expected, but the 'data' property that was modified inside the reduce callback changed dataYear AND dataMonth.

How does dataMonth get modified when I'm not referencing it ?

[image]

Comment: You're indeed references it. dataYear is a [shallow copy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Shallow_copy) of dataMonth. You can perform a [deep copy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Deep_copy) otherwise to ensure that dataMonth isn't mutated.

Comment: Oh I get it, because it's a shallow copy, my object inside dataYear are still referencing the ones in dataMonth. Thank you, I will try to see if it solves it

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I was able to solve my problem by doing a deep clone, please post your answer so I can closed this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@OluwafemiSule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73302129/reduce-callback-modying-wrong-array#comment129455346_73302129) for pointing out that dataMonth was indeed being referenced.

The [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `...` was doing a shallow copy of dataMonth, meaning that my nested objects were still referencing dataMonth.

To create new references for nested objects, I used [structuredClone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) which deep clones my object, thus preventing any mutation of the source object.